# Eclipse - How to config android sdk to helios

Tags: android, eclipse

In my system(Windows Xp) first i integrate the android sdk to Eclipse indigo. But now i want to integrate the android sdk to Eclipse helios.How to do that? I tried but i am not getting. For this i removed the eclipse indigo and corresponding android sdk. after that i downloaded the eclipse helios and android sdk.  open the eclipse it shows the android adk and avd manger icon. it shows error about android sdk path.How to install (like fresh) android sdk in eclipse helios? How to do that please can any body help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just for changing the eclipse, you need not have removed the Android SDK. You can use the same SDK in different versions of Eclipse.
2. When you say you can see the SDK Manager and AVD Manager icons, I assume that you have successfully installed ADT.
3. To correct the Android SDK path error, go to Window -> Preferences -> Android. On the preferences pane, click the Browse button next to SDK Locations and browse to the path where you have installed the Android SDK (For example C:\Android\android-sdk-windows) and click Apply

Comment: Yes, it would be crazy to have two SDKs on your machine, especially as it's so big with all the documentation and samples. Each version of Eclipse will need its own plugin (ADT) so that it can 'see' the SDK

Comment: There are two components to Android development on Eclipse - first is the Android SDK which is required for developing Android apps irrespective of whether you use Eclipse or not and. The next is the ADT plugin which is required to make Eclipse understand Android specific features (DDMS, Shortcut to SDK Manager, ..). Now what is it that you want to remove? The SDK or ADT?

Comment: Actually i removed the android-sdk folder and eclipse folder of indigo for helios android sdk and after i took the new ones(new Eclipse helios and android sdk folder(downloaded from developer guide)) but it shows the SDK Manager and AVD Manager icons in eclipse helios. why? now what i have to do?

Comment: To uninstall ADT, go to Help->About Eclipse -> Installation Details and uninstall Android *.  But you will need ADT for developing Android application on Eclipse.

Comment: i uninstall these Android DDMS, Android Devlelopment Tools,Android Hierarchy Viewer,Android Traceview from eclipse and then restart it. open the eclipse go to help->Install New Software->enter the url and then Mark the Developer tools and then click on the next i got the following error "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)". What it means?

Comment: Looks like your uninstallation was not clean. Would you please try extracting the eclipse that you already downloaded, to a different directory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11420/discussion-between-naresh-and-rajesh)

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided path for the android SDK in the preferences? If not then Go to Window > Preferences > Android and provide path your android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps to add android sdk in eclipse helios

Help->Eclipse Market place->Popular Tab->u can find Android Development Tools for Eclipse ..
and there is install button right to that..click install! ..that's all...